# Finding dominant eigenvector and eigenvalue

Tags: r, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I calculated the eigen of a matrix:

```
e <- eigen(t)
```

Now I need to get the dominant eigenvalue and dominant eigenvector

Is the dominant eigenvalue calculated:

```
e$values[1]
```

And what about the dominant eigenvector? Is it extracted by:

```
e$vectors[,1]
```

I am asking since I thought that e$values will give me the eigenvalues from largest to smallest...but I am getting these results:

```
 [1]  1.000000e+00  3.751736e-01  3.751736e-01 -4.143304e-01 -4.143304e-01
 [6] -4.330604e-01 -4.330604e-01 -7.921977e-02 -7.921977e-02  5.948138e-02
[11]  5.948138e-02  6.969758e-04  6.969758e-04 -4.057858e-02 -4.057858e-02
[16]  3.039333e-02  3.039333e-02  8.007672e-03  8.007672e-03 -2.005426e-02
[21] -2.005426e-02  2.361154e-02  2.361154e-02  1.023211e-02  1.023211e-02
[26]  1.099767e-02  1.099767e-02 -9.547037e-03 -9.547037e-03  1.070972e-02
[31]  1.070972e-02 -1.925037e-03 -1.925037e-03 -2.908073e-03 -2.908073e-03
[36]  1.517843e-04  1.517843e-04 -1.088992e-04 -3.070693e-10  3.070676e-10
```

Answer (score 2):

from the help function:

> values
>
> a vector containing the (p) eigenvalues of x, sorted in decreasing order, according to Mod(values) in the asymmetric case when
>   they might be complex (even for real matrices). For real asymmetric
>   matrices the vector will be complex only if complex conjugate pairs of
>   eigenvalues are detected. vectors
>
> either a (p\times p) matrix whose columns contain the eigenvectors of x, or NULL if only.values is TRUE. The vectors are
>   normalized to unit length.

It says decreasing order, and a matrix whose column contain the vectors, so yes it would be

```
e$values[1]
e$vectors[,1]
```

Dont't forget that if you want more help, you should provide an reproducible example in order us to understand what's wrong